# Centering icon font in css circle, inside of parent

Tags: html, css

Ok so I have 3 css circles with icon fonts centered inside of them, now I cant for the life of me get it centered inside of its parent. Also instead of lining up they are stacking on top of each other, I used float: left to fix this but it messed up my whole hover.

[Take a look here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/), just go to portfolio section and hover over one of the members.

How it is suppose to look:

[image]

How it looks:

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="img-list">
  <li>
    <img src="img/team-member-1.jpg" alt="...">
    <span class="text-content">
        <span>
            <div class="social-icon-holder">
                <span class="ion-social-twitter social-icon"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icon-holder">
                <span class="ion-social-facebook social-icon"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icon-holder">
                <span class="ion-social-dribbble social-icon"></span>
            </div>
            Johnathan Adams
            <p>Developer</p>
        </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* =Team
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.team {
    padding: 180px 0 180px 0;
}

.team img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul.img-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.img-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 350px;
}

span.text-content {
    background: rgba(39,39,39,0.75);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

span.text-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.team span p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}

.social-icon {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.social-icon-holder {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: table;
}

.social-icon-holder:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.social-icon-holder:hover .social-icon {
    color: #272727;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: social-icon-holder should be displayed as inline boxes , such as display:inline-table; or inline-block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap a `<p>` tag around the team members name to make it a block element and essentially put it on  a new line.

Then, in `.social-icon-holder{`

change

```
display:table;
```

to

```
display:inline-block;
```

or

```
display:inline-table;
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQGGs/)

For this JsFiddle, I jut used a placeholder background image.

To get the social icons center, I did this:

```
.social-icon {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QQGGs/3/)

Comment: Ok so this worked great but now my icon fonts that were centered in the circle are off center, did I do something wrong? [Update here](http://aliensix.com/lightningbolt/)

Comment: I gave this a shot but it made the icons disappear, I updated your fiddle so you will be able to see the icons [link](http://jsfiddle.net/QQGGs/2). In theory it makes sense to me but for some reason its not working

Comment: They are still not 100% centered, for example if I make the icon bigger its extremely off center, is there another method I can try?

Comment: They are still center to me, even if I change the font size to 20px? @Dimitrov

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50018/discussion-between-beatalex-and-dimitrov)

Comment: Ok so if you take a look here aliensix.com/lightningbolt you can see they are a bit off center, they are 16px there, sorry my internet cut out, i am in the chat if you want to hop in

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove `display :table` from the class `.social-icon-holder` and then you may add `display: table-cell;` property.

also to align the icons inside the circle you can add `font-size` and a little bit `padding`.

HEre I've just added for facebook icon, but you can apply it on `.social-icon` so apply for all icons.

```
.ion-social-facebook:before {
content: "\f231";
font-size: 2em; /*Added line this will increase the icon size*/
padding-left: .4em;
}
```

Comment: @Dimitrov by using `font-size` and `padding` icons are center inside the circle now?

Answer (score 1):

from my comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h7kJS/ full result : http://jsfiddle.net/h7kJS/2/embedded/result/
`.social-icon-holder` can be displayed as `inline-table`  (`inline-block`+`line-height` works too).

Image should be in absolute under `.text-content` to make things easier :below: update of your CSS (where `.team` was removed for `.img-list` )

```
    /* =Team
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.img-list {/* update */
    padding: 180px 0 180px 0;
}

.img-list img {/* update */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;/* update */
    z-index:0;/* update */
}

ul.img-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.img-list li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 350px;
    width:350px;/* update */
}

span.text-content {
    background: rgba(39,39,39,0.75);
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: table;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

span.text-content span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
    position:relative;/* update */
}

.team span p {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #a5a5a5;
}

.social-icon {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.social-icon-holder {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-table;/* update */
}

.social-icon-holder:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.social-icon-holder:hover .social-icon {
    color: #272727;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: color 0.5s ease;
}
```

Comment: note, prefix for transitions are not really needed anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it ok ? try this code

```
.social-icon-holder {
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;

   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
<span>
 <div class="social">
   <div class="social-icon-holder">
      <span class="ion-social-twitter social-icon"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="social-icon-holder">
      <span class="ion-social-twitter social-icon"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="social-icon-holder">
      <span class="ion-social-twitter social-icon"></span>
   </div>
 </div>
</span>
```

--- stylesheet --

```
.social div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.social-icon{
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```