# position icon in a center of div

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="inlineSearchDiv">
     <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

where the css code looks like following:

```
.inlineSearchDiv {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right:-100px;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I would like to know, how can I force my icon to be in the center of the div element (horizontally & vertically)? Here was my try:

```
.inlineSearchDiv i {
    -moz-transform: translate(0,50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0,50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,50%);
    transform: translate(0,50%);


}
```

however shall the height of the `inlineSearchDiv` changed, then my `transform` property was no longer refreshed

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502660/centering-icon-font-in-css-circle-inside-of-parent

Answer (score 1):

Forget the `transform`. Add this to your CSS:

```
 .fa-search { vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: I have replaced my .inlineSearchDiv i {} with your line, but unfortunately it did not work. Still aligned to the top

Answer (score 0):

Based on the recommendations I changed my code to the following:

```
 .inlineSearchDiv i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See my answer. transform is not correct for your problem.